# How and when are different memory maps created?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, operating-system, embedded

An Excerpt from one of the books I'm referring quotes,

> - **The processor memory map**: This is the first memory map that needs to be created. It explains the CPU’s memory management policies such
>     as how the CPU handles the different address spaces (user mode, kernel
>     mode), what are the caching policies for the various memory regions,
>     and so on.
> - **The board memory map**: Once there is an idea of how the processor sees the various memory areas, the next step is to fit the various
>     onboard devices into the processor memory areas. This requires an
>     understanding of the various onboard devices and the bus controllers.
> - **The software memory map**: Next a portion of the memory needs to be given for the various software components such as the boot loader and
>     the Linux kernel. The Linux kernel sets up its own memory map and
>     decides where the various kernel sections such as code and heap will
>     reside.

When are these memory maps created ? Like say, is it something hard coded and before the compilation phase or is it decided by some run time task ?

Are there some standards on mapping the processor address space to various devices or is it the user's choice ?

The [book](http://www.amazon.in/Embedded-Linux-System-Design-Development/dp/0849340586) btw.

Answer (score 0):

> When are these memory maps created ? Like say, is it something hard
>   coded and before the compilation phase or is it decided by some run
>   time task ?

The configuration for this would typically be the first thing the kernel would do when starting. It can be hard coded or could be decided before the kernel starts, i.e. in the bootloader.

> Are there some standards on mapping the processor address space to
>   various devices or is it the user's choice ?

It is really up to you as the designer. Many would probably choose a similar configuration from other operating system such as linux.

Comment: So the consideration of using port mapped I/O or memory mapped I/O lies totally in the hands of the system developer ?

Comment: Yes, I would say so.

Comment: @RohitMat: No! It is typically defined by the underlying hardware. Not sure what you mean with "port-mapped IO, that's typically a hack if you don't have an external bus on an MCU and use an IO-port to emulate one  with bit-banding. You might mean serpratre memory and IO address spaces, but that's given by the CPU and with modern CPUs a legacy. Most larger (16+ bits) RISC don't support a seperate IP-address space and for x86, it is only used for legacy stuff like PS/2 keyboard interface and old UART/Parallel port peripherals, etc.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the clarification on Port mapped I/O. I meant the same thing. So its hardware dependent stuff. So the board memory map depends on the hardware right ? What about the software memory map ?

Comment: @RohitMat: The software map apparently depends on the hardware, unless you run into a virtual machine, in which case it - of course - depends on another software (the VM) **and** that's underlying hardware. Etc..